# Implementing a no-op std::ostringstream that can be accepted as a std::ostringstream reference

Tags: c++, reference, stream

Can anyone suggest a way to have a *null* `std::ostringstream` that avoids doing any work on the parameters passed to it with `<<`?

There are two related posts here [Implementing a no-op std::ostream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760301/implementing-a-no-op-stdostream) and [Printing to nowhere with ostream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818371/printing-to-nowhere-with-ostream) , so far the most promising solution is https://stackoverflow.com/a/760353/826203 , but while test it

```
int main() {
    onullstream os;
    os << 666;

//  std::ostringstream & oss = os; // error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'onullstream' to 'std::ostringstream &'
    oss << "hello, world";
}
```

however, this could only be used like `os<<666`, but could *not* be used as a `std::ostringstream &`. any way out here?

Comment: You get an error because `std::ostringstream` and `onullstream` are different parts of the inheritance tree. While both inherits from `std::ostream` they are otherwise unrelated. Instead I think the requirement to use `std::ostringstream` here is a false requirement, something that you don't really need. For example, if you have a function that you call with the stream you would have it take a `std::ostream` reference. Then you could pass a `std::ostringstream` object *or* a `onullstream` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to create a non-operational stream is to actually not create a custom stream class but rather to disable an existing stream. For example, you can disable formatting to an `std::ostream` by setting its stream buffer to null:

```
std::ostringstream out;
out.std::ostream::rdbuf(0);
// any attempt to write anything to out will fail.
```

If you need a stream which successfully fails to format data you can create a stream buffer which doesn't store any bytes and is always successful. However, when using this stream buffer the actually formatting will be performed:

```
struct nullbuf: std::streambuf {
    std::streambuf::int_type overflow(std::streambuf::int_type c) {
        return std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(c);
    }
};
// ...
nullbuf            buf;
std::ostringstream out;
out.std::ostream::rdbuf(&buf);
```

Note that I would also recommend **not** to have functions take a `std::ostringstream` as arguments. Instead, any function which doesn't construct the stream should travel in terms of `std::ostream&`. If your existing interfaces already take an `std::ostringstream` you can create a a null stream by deriving from `std::ostringstream` and setting the stream buffer appropriately:

```
class onullstream
    : private virtual nullbuf
    , public std::ostringstream {
public:
    nullstring()
        : std::ios(this)
        , std::ostringstgream() {
        this->std::ostream::rdbuf(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you! May I ask 1) what do you mean by "the actually formatting will be performed", and 2)  why recommend not to take a `std::ostringstream` as arguments, instead, take `std::ostream&`?

Comment: @athos: sorry, I keep forgetting that the derived streams have overloads for `rdbuf()` (which are rather misguided). Just direct the call to `std::ios`-version of the function, e.g.: `out.std::ostream::rdbuf(&buf)` (likewise for the other version).

Comment: @athos: with respect to your other questions: 1. the `nullbuf` simply eats all characters sent to it. However, since it is successful all characters are produced. That is, when you insert, e.g., an `int` the `int` will be transformed into a sequence of `char`s representing the `int`'s value and the `char`s won't be used. That is, there is potentially a substantial amount of work done just for ignoring characters! Invalidating the stream fairly forcibly, i.e., setting the stream buffer to `0`, causes the stream operations to not convert the value but all operations fail.

Comment: @athos: whether the stream failing matters, I don't know - most likely it doesn't: output streams are rarely tested for successful operations. Note, that in all cases the actual arguments are evaluated. For example, when using `out << f()` the function `f()` is called but the result isn't used or, at least, the characters are not used.
For 2.: formatting generally doesn't care what stream it gets - it could be an `std::ostringstream`, an `std::ofstream`, or some other custom stream. Correspondingly, the functions are best off traveling in terms of `std::ostream&`.

Comment: @athos: I also updated the code in the answer (which still haven't compiled - I'm currently using a mobile device. It shoudl be sufficient to direct the compiler to call the base class version of `rdbuf()`.

Comment: @athos: well, there was a `public` missing to make the default constructor accessible.

Comment: Thank you! I just update your code, pls check if it's what you mean? Still two more questions: 1. am I understand it correctly, that in *all* 3 approaches, the formmating will take pace, i.e. all characters are produced -- when you insert, e.g., an int the int will be transformed into a sequence of chars representing the int's value and the chars won't be used. 2. in the #2 and #3 approach, what will be the `c` to be passed into `std::streambuf::int_type overflow(std::streambuf::int_type c)`? will it be `0`, so that it's almost the same as approach #1 that has 0 length buffer?